# Zip Deploy Azure function to the Azure Portal using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

I have a query regarding deploying the Azure function in the portal using the CLI.

I have created the storage account, resource group and created instance for the function app as well.

I created one normal azure http trigger function.

After that I have executed the command to deploy the Azure function using CLI. My command is executing without any issues but when I check the same in the portal changes are not reflecting.

Please help me to resolve the issue .

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Manikanta

Comment: Please check did you meet the requirements, especially the project file struct.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-zip-file-requirements

Comment: You need to restart the app ? have you done that /

Comment: I have done that part also by restarting the app after executing the command. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by George and Thomas.

Please make sure to meet the requirements, especially the project file struct.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#deployment-zip-file-requirements

After deployment , restart the app.

Comment: What is the shared code in the folder structure mentioned for Azure function zip deployment.?